# Is it possible to have multiple span classes on the same line without using div?

Tags: html, css

I want to have each text have a different color so I used a multiple span classes to set the color in css. I also want the text to have line breaks so I used div. This fiddle shows the result I want but the div tags used for the line breaks creates a large gap. Is there another way to have line breaks with multiple span classes?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nh7vswco/

```
                <pre id="info">
       
                <div class = "fact-card">               
                <span class="animal">  animal</span>
                <span class="colon"> : </span>
                <span class="animal-name">tiger</span>
                <span class="comma">,</span> 
                </div> 
                
                <div class = "fact-card">
                <span class="animal">  species</span>
                <span class="colon"> : </span>
                <span class="animal-name">Mammal</span>
                <span class="comma">,</span>
                </div>
                
                <div class = "fact-card">
                <span class="animal">  type</span>
                <span class="colon"> : </span>
                <span class="animal-name">carnivore</span>
                <span class="comma">,</span>
                </div>
```

```
Result:
Each word and colon should have a different color.
animal : tiger,
species : mammal,
type : carnivore,
```

This fiddle has the result Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nh7vswco/ but I would like to remove the gaps from the div tag.

Comment: you can use `<ul><li>` or `<ol><li>` for line break, Also you can use ::after pseudo element css for colon and comma.

Comment: In your code, you have `<pre>` tag at top of your context. That gap you mentioned is because of `<pre>`. read more about `<pre>` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Answer (score 0):

This issue is actually due to the side-effects of using the `pre` tag. The additional spacing you have in between the `div`s inside your `pre` tag are being interpreted as line breaks as that is what `pre` is meant to do. If you do not want this extra spacing, eliminate the extra white space (line breaks, spaces, etc.) you have.

```html
                <pre id="info"><div class = "fact-card">               
                <span class="animal">  animal</span>
                <span class="colon"> : </span>
                <span class="animal-name">tiger</span>
                <span class="comma">,</span> 
                </div><div class = "fact-card">
                <span class="animal">  species</span>
                <span class="colon"> : </span>
                <span class="animal-name">Mammal</span>
                <span class="comma">,</span>
                </div><div class = "fact-card">
                <span class="animal">  type</span>
                <span class="colon"> : </span>
                <span class="animal-name">carnivore</span>
                <span class="comma">,</span>
                </div>
```

Comment: This does remove the space but all the text is stacked on top of each other making it unreadable.

Comment: If you want one line break separating each line of code, just add one line break between the divs.

Answer (score 0):

1- There are many ways to make a line break like so: `<br>` or [line-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-break) CSS property.

2- To remove the gaps from the div tag. we can use the `line-height: 0%;`

```css
<style>#info {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
 
  .colon {
    color: #cc7832;
  }
  .animal-name {
    color: #2587be;
  }
  .animal {
    color:#9473a5;
    display: block;
  }
  .fact-card{
    display: flex; 
    line-height: 0%;
  } 
  .span {
    font-family: Arial;
  }
```

```html
  <pre id="info">
       
    <div class = "fact-card">               
    <span class="animal">  animal</span>
    <span class="colon"> : </span>
    <span class="animal-name">tiger</span>
    <span class="comma">,</span> 
    </div> 
    
    <div class = "fact-card">
    <span class="animal">  species</span>
    <span class="colon"> : </span>
    <span class="animal-name">Mammal</span>
    <span class="comma">,</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class = "fact-card">
    <span class="animal">  type</span>
    <span class="colon"> : </span>
    <span class="animal-name">carnivore</span>
    <span class="comma">,</span>
    </div>
  </pre>
```